# How to add a name to ApplicationContext by application.property

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a basic spring boot application I am trying to add a name to my ApplicationCotext and print it but I do not sure how to do it:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CompanyApplication.class, args);
    System.out.println(ctx.getApplicationName() + " running");
```

On my application.property file I added this:

```
spring.application.name=Company-Application
```

But it just not working (print only "running")

Any idea how to add a name to my ApplicationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.application.name` actually configures the context ID which you can get it from :

```java
    System.out.println(ctx.getId() + " running");
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, but what is configuring getApplicationName()?

Comment: i am afraid it does not support .Or what is your concern of using `ctx.getId()` to get the value of `spring.application.name` ?

Comment: No concern I just wonder how to use getApplicationName() and which method or property give it a name?